# Issue with overloaded = function

Tags: c++

Here is my issue.

I have a class called AguiFont. It internally has a pointer to whatever type of font the font loader is set to. I overloaded the = operator so that users wouldn't ever have to manage its memory.

It works great except for one circumstance. When I set the font for a widget in its constructor, for some reason when I come to use that font, I get 0xfefefe which is due to the memory at that pointer already being freed. If in a function in main I create some fonts and ='d them it's fine. And when i call someWidget.setFont() that is fine too, but calling setFont(); in the constructor causes the issue.

Here is the overloaded = operator:

```
AguiFont& AguiFont::operator=(const AguiFont &tmp)
{
    loader->destroyFont(nativeFontPtr);

    nativeFontPtr = 0;
    if(tmp.getFont())
        this->nativeFontPtr = loader->loadFont(tmp.getPath().c_str(),tmp.getSize());

    this->fontLineHeight = tmp.getLineHeight();
    this->fontPath = tmp.getPath();
    this->fontSize = tmp.getSize();

    return *this;
}
```

Here is the constructor for a widget: (I have it loading a test font which should indeed succeed)

```
AguiWidget::AguiWidget(void)
{
    location = AguiPoint(0,0);
    size = AguiSize(0,0);

    parentWidget = 0;
    dockingStyle = DockingNone;
    userData = 0;
    opacity = 1.0f;
    setFont(AguiFont(std::string("test.ttf"),24));
    tintColor = AguiColor(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,opacity);
    fontColor = AguiColor(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
    isWidgetVisible = true;
    isWidgetEnabled = true;
    isWidgetFocusable = false;
    isWidgetTabable = false;
    clipChildren = true;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You might find [this FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/) interesting.

Comment: @Konrad: What do you mean? Convert my comment into an answer? I'm pretty sure I'd get downvotes for that :)

Comment: @Fred: that’s what I meant. It *is* the correct answer in this context, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm inclined to blame the copy ctor (which you don't show). If the font is copied when a temporary is created, the first destructor will probably call `loader->destroyFont(nativeFontPtr);`. If the copy ctor didn't duplicate `nativeFontPtr`, this will destroy the single underlying font as soon as the temporary goes out of scope.

Comment: What should my copy constructor look like for this, i'm not sure how to have both working together.

Comment: "Rule of three": If you need a copy constructor, destructor or assignment operator, you probably need all three of them. But often the assignment operator can be as simple as `AguiFont tmp(source); this->swap(tmp); return *this;`. This reuses the copy ctor and the swap function.

Answer (score 0):

What is the signature of setFont ? It looks like it could be that you are missing the copy constructor for AguiFont.

Comment: Yes it has no copy constructor.